# how to make pick & choose image slide for each products of a shopping site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I need someone to suggest me how can i make an image slide,where you can pick & choose an image of a particular product. Similar to flipkart side , as shown here:

http://www.flipkart.com/united-colors-benetton-men-s-checkered-casual-shirt/p/itmdzbs2jwtc3ez8?pid=SHTDZBRTBWYZEAJF&ref=8b1e929b-3454-466b-be71-49ab1fc8654c

As it can be seen, below product image, there are few images shown where you can choose to view that one.

I've seen many slide examples but not similar to this one. How to get start with this?

Answer (score 0):

i think this  will help you...

```
  <div id="bigpic" class="b">
            <img src="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/big/iphone-3-big.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View" />

            <p id="desc">iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View</p>

        </div>

        <div id="thumbs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/big/iphone-1-big.jpg" rel="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-1-small.jpg">
                        <img src="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-1-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle Front View In Blue!" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/big/iphone-2-big.jpg" rel="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-2-small.jpg">
                        <img src="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-2-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle Dual View Grey!" />
                    </a>
                </li
                >
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/big/iphone-3-big.jpg" rel="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-3-small.jpg">
                        <img src="http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/images/small/iphone-3-small.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle 16GB Zoom View" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#thumbs ul li a').hover(
    function() {
        var currentBigImage = $('#bigpic img').attr('src');
        var newBigImage = $(this).attr('href');
        var currentThumbSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
        switchImage(newBigImage, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc);
    },
    function() {}
);



function switchImage(imageHref, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc) {

    var theBigImage = $('#bigpic img');

    if (imageHref != currentBigImage) {

        theBigImage.fadeOut(250, function(){
            theBigImage.attr('src', imageHref).fadeIn(250);

            var newImageDesc = $("#thumbs ul li a      img[src='"+currentThumbSrc+"']").attr('alt');
            $('p#desc').empty().html(newImageDesc);
        });

    }

}

    });
   </script>
```

jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/chinmayahd/JvkGb/

created using this one:
http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/

If you want to add any jquery image slide plugins
check here
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/